# Is there a binding file for EcmaScript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, built-in

for a project, I want to write a program to generate "valid" and random javascript code, by "valid" I mean don't generate javascript code which are going to throw an error. For example if my program call the javascript function **every()**:

```
var arr1 = [ 1, 2, "foo"]
/* this is the case I want to avoid */
arr1.every([3,4,5])

/* this is one of the case that I want */
arr1.every(function() { /* do stuff here */ })
```

(I know I can't produce 100% valid javascript code, but my goal is to produce the most valid javascript code possible)
To do this, I need to know for every function what arguments are excepted by the function the, what the function return.

I've tried to scrape [msdn-javascript-reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) to have a list of all buits-in objects and functions and have an idea about what they except and then build a db. But this is hard because msdn isn't well structured for scrapping because and provide information in an unstructured format. So  is there a site, or db where I can have all javascript bindings ?
Thank you !

Comment: Why do you find it unstructured? Each functions page has subsections for "Parameters" (unless they don't have any) and "Return value" right under the "Syntax" section, which is what you seem to need. You can just go to each url on the page you've linked - if they have those sections, then scrape as function; otherwise,  see if they have sections for "Static methods" and "Instance methods" and go scrape links from *those* sections....

Comment: Yeah you're right. I've found a solution. I recover all code examples of a function, then I decorate this function to check the types and the value of the return and args.